# Cleaning up strings when EXIT_FAILURE occurs, instead of exit(0)

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

So when `exit(0)` happens, the strings are magically cleaned up, and `valgrind` reports no leaks.

When `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` occurs, which it can at multiple points, `valgrind` reports "possible leaks" for a bunch of C++ strings I created.

How can I clean them up when I know that exit_failure happens?

edit: I am referring to strings I created like this:

line 22 `string include = "#include";`

Valgrind:

```
==42430== 
==42430== HEAP SUMMARY:
==42430==     in use at exit: 100,201 bytes in 22 blocks
==42430==   total heap usage: 33 allocs, 11 frees, 101,121 bytes allocated
==42430== 33 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 6 of 22
==42430==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42430==    by 0x4EF2568: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==42430==    by 0x4EF2676: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==42430==    by 0x4EF42D5: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==42430==    by 0x401C5A: processOneFile(std::istream&, std::ostream&, Node*, std::string) (include.cc:22)
==42430==    by 0x402497: processOneFile(std::istream&, std::ostream&, Node*, std::string) (include.cc:99)
==42430==    by 0x402C82: main (include.cc:172)
```

Comment: Wait, if the program is exiting, does it matter? The OS will free up the memory allocated to the program anyway. Also an example would be nice.

Comment: What you really have to watch out for with `exit` is all those destructors that may have done important things not running. Unless the program must be terminated with the subtlety of a headsman's axe, `return` your way back out and exit normally.

Comment: Or since this is C++ and anything that calls `exit` should be pretty exceptional, throw an exception and get all that stack unrolling goodness on your side.

Comment: I thought exit 0 DID run all those things, while exit_failure doesn't. Can you please be more specific about the exception? Where? What am I trying? What am I throwing? Am I supposed to use it to replace all of my if statements that cause it to exit_failure?

Comment: @Ben It matters if you want to use valgrind to find *actual* leaks and something is cluttering up the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comment that got out of hand.

To recap, Memory isn't much of a problem here. The program is terminating as a result of `exit`, so leaks are leaks for at most a couple milliseconds. Yipeee!

What you really have to watch out for with exit is all those destructors that may have done important things not running, like flushing data to screen or files, politely hanging up network connections, and releasing resources that aren't managed by the OS. Unless the program must be terminated immediately with the subtlety of a headsman's axe, `return` your way back to `main` and exit normally.

If this isn't an option, or since this is C++ and anything that calls `exit` should be pretty exceptional, `throw` an exception and get all that stack unrolling goodness on your side.

@user I'd have to see your code to make good suggestions. You can test with something as simple as `throw "Oh crap!";`, but typically I'll extend `std::exception` something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
class Failure: public std::exception
{
private:
    std::string mErrMsg;

public:
    Failure(std::string errMsg):mErrMsg(errMsg)
    {
        // does nothing
    }
    const char* what() const noexcept
    {
        return mErrMsg.c_str();
    }
};
```

Then in place of `exit`, I put: `throw Failure("description");`. For example,

```
void function()
{
    // does stuff
    if (bad_stuff_happened)
    {
        throw Failure("description of the bad stuff that happened");
    }
}
```

Then I wrap my `main` or some other low-level function in a try/catch block to log the error. Here it is with `main`:

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        function();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch (Failure &excp)
    {
        std::cerr << excp.what();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

And the output of this is

```
description of the bad stuff that happened
```

in stderr.

I do not `throw` for `exit(0)` and I don't recommend that you do either. I don't recommend `exit(0)` either. A good program result should be a very common, as in  not exceptional circumstances, and be handled through the regular flow of code.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a memory leak. Once the process has exited the OS will reclaim the heap memory associated with it. When you free memory what you are generally doing is adjusting heap allocation accounting information local to your application.

Comment: While the question specifically mentions strings, what about objects that have references to external resources, and really do need proper cleanup (i.e. running their destructors)?

Comment: The OS _should_ clean up things like file handles as well. If you have flushed all your writes to disk .etc. then you are probably safe but assuring data is actually really safely written to disk is a far more complicated topic than that :)

As long as you close/flush file handles and network sockets after you've finished writing to them it shouldn't be an issue.

AFIK. Git is a good example of software that deliberately does not close resources or free memory beyond necessity because it has no plans on running continuously.

Comment: That's exactly the point I was making. If you don't flush after every write, there will be stuff buffered. Since the destructor never gets called, the buffer never gets flushed, so you end up with incomplete data in any files.

Comment: @Barmar Fair enough :)